# Add values in a lists which is a string column in hive

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

I have a set of data where a columns consists of lists which is of string data type.

```
Column_A|Column_B
AAA     |1 23 56 89 74 52
BBB     |63 99 44 2 80 87 58 63
CCC     |96 45 23 84 62 74
```

Here, In the above data I need to add the values in column B as below:

```
Column_A|Column_B              |Column_C
AAA     |1 23 56 89 74 52      |295
BBB     |63 99 44 2 80 87 58 63|496
CCC     |96 45 23 84 62 74     |384
```

I have used cast function and converted the data type from string to int using the below query.

```
select Column_A,cast (Column_B as INT) as Column_B from Xyz
```

But summing the values is a great challenge.
Can someone help me out?

I'm learning RegEx too.. Is there any possibility to use RegEx?

Comment: The _correct_ solution is to normalize the data e.g. store as `(AAA, 1), (AAA, 23), (AAA, 52)`. And not _store_ the sum but calculate it on demand `SELECT SUM(b) GROUP BY a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Explode` your column using `split` by space and aggregate.

This is demo in Hive:

```
with your_data as
(
select Column_A,Column_B from 
(
select stack(3,
'AAA','1 23 56 89 74 52',
'BBB','63 99 44 2 80 87 58 63',
'CCC','96 45 23 84 62 74'
             ) as (Column_A,Column_B)
)s
) --Use your table instead of this CTE

select Column_A,Column_B, sum(cast(b.val_b as int)) as Column_C
  from your_data a
       lateral view outer explode(split(Column_B,' ')) b as val_b
group by Column_A,Column_B;
```

Result:

```
OK
AAA     1 23 56 89 74 52        295
BBB     63 99 44 2 80 87 58 63  496
CCC     96 45 23 84 62 74       384
Time taken: 53.228 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Alternatively, if the maximum number of elements in the list is fixed, you can do the same without explode, it will work much faster:

```
create temporary macro cast_value(s string) nvl(cast(s as int),0);

with your_data as
    (
    select Column_A,Column_B from 
    (
    select stack(3,
    'AAA','1 23 56 89 74 52',
    'BBB','63 99 44 2 80 87 58 63',
    'CCC','96 45 23 84 62 74'
                 ) as (Column_A,Column_B)
    )s
    ) --Use your table instead of this CTE

    select Column_A,Column_B, 
           cast_value(col_B_array[0])+ 
           cast_value(col_B_array[1])+
           cast_value(col_B_array[2])+
           cast_value(col_B_array[3])+
           cast_value(col_B_array[4])+
           cast_value(col_B_array[5])+
           cast_value(col_B_array[6])+
           cast_value(col_B_array[7])+
           cast_value(col_B_array[8])+
           cast_value(col_B_array[9]) as Column_C
    from(
        select Column_A,Column_B, split(Column_B,' ') col_B_array
          from your_data a
    )s
```

Result:

```
OK
AAA     1 23 56 89 74 52        295
BBB     63 99 44 2 80 87 58 63  496
CCC     96 45 23 84 62 74       384
Time taken: 0.82 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```